# Plotting a $\cos$ function within a specific domain

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Lef $f$ be an odd function with period $\pi$ defined by $f(x)=\cos(x)$ where $0<x\leq \pi/2$.
Plot the graph of $f$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$.
The answer in my book is this:
[image]

But I don't understand why it isn't as follows: (My guess)
[image]

Could anybody explain to me?

Comment: Would your graph define an odd function?

Comment: No, but why should it?

Comment: Your very first sentence is "Let $f$ be an **odd** function with period $\pi$..."

Comment: That's right but I also know that my $x$ is between $0<x\leq \pi/2$.

Comment: Yes, and that should inform you about the value of $f$ in the range $-\pi/2\leq x <0$.  Do you remember the definition of an odd function?  The periodicity determines the rest of the values.

Comment: I will try to remember that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that an **odd function** is a function $f$ such that $f(x)=-f(-x)$.  This is tantamount to taking the graph of the function to the right of the $y$-axis and reflecting it about the $x$-axis and $y$-axis consecutively.  Thus, your graph should have some negative values in the range $[-\pi/2,0)$, which yours does not.

This determines the values of the function on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ (though admittedly your function isn't defined at $0$, which could easily be corrected by defining it to be any value, say $0$).  Notice that the length of this interval is $\pi$.  Since $f$ is required to be periodic, this means that the values of $f$ on each interval $[-\pi/2+n\pi,\pi/2+n\pi]$ is determined by the values of $f$ on the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, which is precisely what we just found.  Thus, $f$ is completely determined (except at the pesky points $x=n\pi$, but as mentioned before, you can just pick some arbitrary value)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I want to calculate my $b_n$ terms of the series. Why is $b_n =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi /2}^{\pi /2} f(x)\cdot \sin (2nx) dx $? I am OK with the $\sin (2nx)$ but not with the coefficient $\frac{2}{\pi}$. Could you explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

For an odd function:
$$\large f(x)=-f(-x)$$